# p:fileDownload is working in Firefox, but only refresh page in Chrome

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use this code to download file in JSF and it's working fine in Firefox. But when I use Chrome it's always refresh page and i don't know  the reason why?

I use Primefaces 6.0

JSF Button

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>

<ui:composition template="../layout/template.xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">

<!-- some code -->>
<p:commandLink
          id="customerExport"
          onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(startLoading, stopLoading)"
          process="productsForm"
          ajax="false">
       <p:fileDownload value="#{productsController.exportProduct()}"/>
       <h:outputText escape = "true" style ="padding: 5px 6px !important;"
            value="#{lang['common.button.export']}" class="btn btn-blue" />
</p:commandLink> 

</ui:composition>
```

Controller

```java
public StreamedContent exportProduct() {
        try {
            //some code


            StreamedContent exportResult = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(exportFile), "application/excel", fileName);
            return exportResult;
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            logger.error("Error: ", ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It's log tomcat

```
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getNavigationCase JSF1090: Navigation case not resolved for component j_idt144.
09-Aug-2019 16:21:58.427 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-267] com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.throwIt Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
 org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

When I clicked the button in Firefox it's loading and download the file (open download file dialog). But when I use Chrome it's always refresh page. I thought it's because it's submit form or something.

Comment: Check out this github issue https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1100

Comment: Always add version info.... always...

Comment: sorry i edit version and logs. anyone help me? :< @bidishamukherjee it's not work man :<

Comment: Did you **try** PF 7?

Comment: no my work have to be used PF 6.0 man. :<

Comment: TRY, not switch in production...!!! and please stop using 'man' at the end of your sentences

Comment: sorry man. no.. i mean thank you i'll try it.

Comment: So what is 'j_idt144'? Assign explicit id's in your [mcve] and post that

Answer (score 0):

This is working in PF7 and with Firefox 68.0.1 and with Chrome 76.0.3809 in Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS.
xhtml

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        function start() {
            PF('statusDialog').show();
        }

        function stop() {
            PF('statusDialog').hide();
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
......................
    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false">
            <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />
        </p:dialog>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="Download" 
                ajax="false"
                onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" 
                icon="pi pi-arrow-down" 
                actionListener="#{manageBean.exportProduct}">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{manageBean.file}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>
```

ManageBean

```
 private StreamedContent file;

 ....

   public void exportProduct() {
    try {
        //some code
        File exportFile =  new File("/home/tsotzo/Desktop/test.xlsx");
        String fileName = "test.xlsx";

        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(exportFile), "application/excel", fileName);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error: ", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explicitly add your chrome version (since google is becomming more and more evil, version numbers become more and more important, so we know when something works(worked))